# StreamReader not working properly

Tags: c#, winforms

Can some body explain me what happens ?

Wen i use this url code is working Label1 post remote page inside in my one

```
string url = "http://ireland.angloinfo.com/";
```

but this one not Label1 empty

```
string url = "http://cyprus.angloinfo.com/";

string html = string.Empty;
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
html = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

Label1.Text = html;
```

what went wrong ?

Comment: You tell us what went wrong so that we can possibly tell you how to fix it.

Comment: Btw, checked it with a simple `new WebClient().DownloadString(url)`, works also only for the first url. The second url returns an empty string. Use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what happens.

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer is somewhat different from mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just checked, and your code returns a myhttpWebResponse with Status = "OK" and ContentLenght = 0, so everything was OK - it is just the server that returned no-data-at-all. The question is, why. Maybe you did not add some headers that are required by it?

I've just tried with setting:

```
string url = "http://cyprus.angloinfo.com/";

string html = string.Empty;
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "yummy";
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
html = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();

Label1.Text = html;
```

and the page seems to download properly. BTW. Why don't you use `WebClient` class instead? You'd have less problems in case of sessions and redirects..

Comment: You should also suggest [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to solve such http traffic issues.

Comment: Actually, I use wireshark or putty or I just enable dumping the .Net network logs (yep, possible with some .config flags). But in this very case, it was not needed - everything was visible in the .Net/VS debugger.. In httprequest/httpresponse objects the headers were easily readable. But, sure, whatever tool to dump the communication is a good addition!

Answer (score 4):

Add the following before you get the response:

```
    HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    myHttpWebRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0";
```

Your code is correct but it seems that the webserver returns empty response to requests with no `User-Agent` field specified in request header.

Answer (score 1):

What about this code:

```
 List<string> lines = new List<string>();
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(WebRequest.Create("http://cyprus.angloinfo.com/").GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
  string line;
  while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
      lines.Add(line);
  }
  label1.Text = String.Join(" ", lines.ToArray());
```